# Cloud Functions with Firestore error "Deadline Exceeded"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently testing out the new **firestore** but I always get the same problem that it tells me something about **Deadline exceeded**

```
{ Error: Deadline Exceeded
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:554:15
  code: 16,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }
```

This is my current code which seems  fine (and works when I deploy it to Firebase)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("./xxxxxxxx-firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.registerUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(event.data.uid).set({
    name: 'Test User',
    country: 'USA'
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
});
```

It also shows this message **Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value**

Comment: “Deadline Exceeded” happens because of the Firestore limits.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47844661/4860874

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Cloud Functions triggers, you need to [return a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) that becomes resolved when the work is complete.  The set() method on the document return a promise, so you should return it to let Cloud Functions know when it's safe to clean up the function:

```
exports.registerUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(event.data.uid).set(...)
});
```

Comment: @JeromeGoldstein Why don't you ask this as a separate question since it's not directly related to the problem here?

Comment: I seem to run into this while using an `async` function as the `onRun` param of the Firebase function. If `async` functions always return a promise, could you perhaps shed some light as to why this error still happening?