# How to resolve/return a forEach function in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following (sample) array:

```
pages = [ {
  "name" : "Hello",
  "id" : 123
},{
  "name" : "There",
  "id" : 987
},{
  "name" : "Great",
  "id" : 555
}  ];
```

I want to save every object in this array as Document in a Collection.
Therefor I have the following function:

```
exports.testSaveFacebookPages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    let userUid = req.body.uid  

// pages array is available here...

    const PagesRef = admin.firestore().collection(`/users/${userUid}/pages/`)
    return pages.forEach(function(page, index){
      PagesRef.doc(`p${index}`).update(page, { merge: true })
    });

    res.status(200).send('Pages saved successfull!');
  }); // cors...
}); // exports...
```

When the function get executed, it saves the pages to the Firestore :)
But it seems the function getting executed in a loop. The logging say:

```
Function execution started
Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

I've readed: [Cloud Functions with Firestore error "Dealine Exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736472/cloud-functions-with-firestore-error-dealine-exceeded) and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

But I could not find any Cloud Function example with a forEach.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning out of your function before you ever send a response.  If you never send a response, your HTTPS function will time out.

Instead, you should be collecting *all* the promises from *all* the updates into an array, then wait for all of them to resolve before sending the final response.  Something like this:

```
exports.testSaveFacebookPages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    let userUid = req.body.uid  

    const PagesRef = admin.firestore().collection(`/users/${userUid}/pages/`)
    const promises = []
    pages.forEach(function(page, index){
      const promise = PagesRef.doc(`p${index}`).update(page, { merge: true })
      promises.push(promise)
    })

    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
      res.status(200).send('Pages saved successfull!')
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send('error')
    })
  })
})
```