# vue.js - error Uncaught TypeError DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: javascript, vue.js

good morning,
I just started seeing Se.
my goal is to create an app with Vue to read data from firestore.
I initialized firestore in my main.js but when I start the app it gives me the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hFOn.png)

this is my main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')

const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

const db = new Firestore({
  projectId: 'myfiresite-88939',
  keyFilename: 'c:/Users/emanu/Documents/myfiresite-88939-ab83a8f33460.json',
});

const docRef = db.collection('users').doc('alovelace');

docRef.set({
  first: 'Ada',
  last: 'Lovelace',
  born: 1815
});
```

I couldn't figure out where I'm wrong, can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736472/cloud-functions-with-firestore-error-deadline-exceeded

Comment: i try this but result is the same
no errors on vue, but the same errors in console and does not write to firestore

Comment: I have looked at many guides, topics etc. but I do not find a solution, in fact I have found 4-5 ways of doing things but none of them work