# google-cloud/firestore: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded while creating document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, grpc, fastify

I'm trying to create document using following code and getting "Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded" while running ref.set() function. I'm using "ws" and "fastify" and there are few number(100-150) of sockets are getting handled. This error is not coming in initial days. Its coming up after 4-5 days after restarting process on server.

```
create: async (id) => {
      //store socket
      return await socketRef.doc(id).set({ id: id, connectedAt: fastify.fsTimestamp() })
    },
```

socketRef = Firestore collection reference

Following is complete error. Not understanding why this happening.

```
{ Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/root/airsniper.api/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/root/airsniper.api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/root/airsniper.api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/root/airsniper.api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback (/root/airsniper.api/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
  code: 4,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'Deadline Exceeded' }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Cloud Function with Firestore returning "Deadline Exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655344/firebase-cloud-function-with-firestore-returning-deadline-exceeded)